# Difference between ini_set("display_errors", "on") and error_reporting(E_ALL)

Tags: php

I tried enabling error display using `php.ini` file, but that didn't work.

Then tried adding `error_reporting(E_ALL)`, didn't work, after that I tried `ini_set("display_errors", "on")`, this option worked for me. My question is how these methods work and when to use which option?

Comment: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php + https://secure.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors

Comment: `display_errors` is a directive for whether to show or not whereas `error_reporting` is a specifier for what error level to really report.So you see if `display_errors` is Off then `error_reporting` won't have any effect.It's like saying "*do you want a candy*"? if you say "*Yes*" then only the question "*Which one?*" has any place.

Answer (score 4):

#### [ini_set()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php)

A simple function to set a `php.ini` configuration at run-time, for that local script.

PHP's docs say

> Sets the value of the given configuration option. The configuration option will keep this new value during the script's execution, and will be restored at the script's ending.

So basically if your PHP config doesn't have error_reporting enabled, you can simply enable it at the top of your script:

```
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

But `ini_set()` is not exclusive for PHP errors, you can set whatever configuration supported by PHP.

```
ini_set('SMTP', 'smtp.gmail.com');
ini_set('smtp_port', 25);
```

---

#### [error_reporting()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)

As per PHP Manual

> error_reporting — Sets which PHP errors are reported

The `error_reporting` function sets the level of visibility of errors to the end-user.

These are some the reporting options you get and what they stand for, most are pretty straight-forward:

- `0`

  - Turns off all PHP errors display
- `E_ALL`

  - shows all errors
- `E_ERROR`

  - Fatal run-time errors. These indicate errors that can not be recovered from, such as a memory allocation problem. Execution of the script is halted.
- `E_WARNING`

  - Run-time warnings (non-fatal errors). Execution of the script is not halted.
- `E_PARSE`

  - Compile-time parse errors. Parse errors should only be generated by the parser.
- `E_NOTICE`

  - Run-time notices. Indicate that the script encountered something that could indicate an error, but could also happen in the normal course of running a script.

---

A little side note I find interesting, remember those key words are constants and they hold integers (numbers), not strings. For example:

```
echo E_ALL; // 32767
echo E_ERROR; // 1
echo E_WARNING; // 2
echo E_PARSE; // 4
echo E_NOTICE; // 8
```

You can view all of PHP's predefined [constants here](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php).